# limit of $u_n = u_{n-1}\cdot \frac{n}{n+1}$ and $v_n = v_{n-1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}$

Tags: limits

What are the limits of $u_n = u_{n-1}.\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $v_n = v_{n-1}.\frac{n+1}{n}$ ?

Seems that $u_n \to 0$ and  $v_n \to \infty$, but I can't prove it.

1. For $u_n$  we have an infinite product of term all strictly lower than $1$. Can we say that goes to 0, and why ?
2. For $v_n$ we have an infinite product of teram all strictly greater than $1$. Can we say that goes to infinity, and why ?

Edit : by induction, $u_n = \frac{u_{1}}{n+1}$ and $v_n = v_{1}.({n+1})$. and thus the result.

But does 1. and 2. are valid statements (Maybe I need to open an other question?).

Comment: Regarding your for u/v questions: Both assumptions are false in general, common counter-examples are can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product:
$\prod\limits_p (1-p^{-2})^{-1}=\zeta(2)$ 
has factors strictly $>1$ and 
$\prod\limits_p (1+p^{-2})^{-1}=\zeta(4)/\zeta(2)$ has factors strictly $<1$.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to consider these as infinite products and, in my opinion, it only clouds the issue by introducing a lot of unnecessary machinery

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Just write out $u(n)$ and $v(n)$ for $n \le 5$ or $n \le 10$, say.

Prove your conjectures for closed forms for $u(n)$ and $v(n)$ by induction.

Now the limits should be easy.

---

For your conjectures, consider the following identities:

$$1 = \sin\frac{\pi}2 = \frac\pi2\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac1{4n^2}\right)\qquad \sinh \frac\pi2 = \frac\pi2\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{4n^2}\right)$$

which demonstrate that such infinite products may converge to nontrivial values (for which a necessary condition is that the individual terms converge to $1$).

See [the Wikipedia lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) for more information.

Comment: Question edited for induction

Comment: @Timmy Yes, that's correct. I've added a bit on infinite products.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well posed, since you didn't specify initial points. Fortunately, convergence of the first sequence doesn't depend on its initial point.

You have 
$$
u_n = u_{n-1}\frac{n}{n+1}.
$$
Then also 
$$
u_{n+1} = u_{n} \frac{n+1}{n+2}.
$$
Combining these facts, we have 
$$
u_{n+1} = u_{n-1}\frac{n}{n+2}.
$$
Show by induction that 
$$
u_{n+k} = u_{n-1} \frac{n}{n+k+1}.
$$
Then since 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+k+1}=0,
$$
we have $u_{n+k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. This implies $u_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

**The behavior of the other sequence will depend on the initial point $v_0$.** If $v_0<0$ then it diverges to $-\infty$, if positive then to positive infinity, and if $v_0=0$ then the sequence converges trivially to 0. Since you didn't specify an initial point, just a recurrence relation, we have no way to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $u_0$ and $v_0$ as any arbitrary numbers. The idea that follows is independent of the  values ​​that $u_0$ and $v_0$ assume.
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
u_n&=& u_{0}\frac{1}{1+1}\cdot\frac{2}{2+1}\cdot\cdot\frac{3}{3+1}\cdot \ldots\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-1)+1} \cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\\
u_n&=& u_{0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot \ldots\cdot\frac{(n-2)}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{n} \cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\\
   &=& u_{0}\frac{1}{n+1}\longrightarrow 0\\
\end{array}
$$
So we entirely analogous
$$
v_n=v_0\cdot \frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\cdot\frac{4}{2}\cdot \ldots\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{n-2}\cdot\frac{(n-2)}{n-1} \cdot\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot \cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\\ =v_0\cdot(n+1)\longrightarrow \mbox{sgn}(u_0)\infty, \quad\mbox{ if } v_0\neq 0.
$$
In general if the product is a telescopic  product  ( exemple $\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{f(k)}{f(k-1)}=\frac{f(n)}{f(0)}$ ) and there is $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{f(0)}=L\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ then
$$
x_n=
\begin{cases}
x_0,& \mbox{ if } n=0\\
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{f(k)}{f(k-1)}x_0,& \mbox{ if } n>0\\
\end{cases}
\implies 
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L\cdot x_0
$$